# Merge commits filtering by author - Git

Tags: git

```
git rebase --interactive some_commit~
```

Gives me a list of commits from `some_commit` till `HEAD`.

```
git log --author some_author --oneline some_commit..
```

Gives me a list of commits by `some_author` from `some_commit` till `HEAD`.

How could I rebase with just the commits from second list? This is deleting commits not by `some_author`.

## Update

I found some way, but some step is missing from my mind:

```
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 commit3 ...
```

How could I get `commit1 commit2 commit3 ...` if my output from second command is:

```
commit1 message1
commit2 message2
commit3 message3
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, `cherry-pick` is the way to do this.  You can replace `--oneline` with `--pretty=%H` in your log command to have it list only the commit IDs. You'll likely want to add `--reverse` as well to get the commits listed from first to last, rather than from most recent to oldest as usual. You can do the entire thing in one command with:

```
git cherry-pick $(git log --pretty=%H --reverse --author some_author some_commit..)
```

Comment: I have to solve conflicts in each step/commit, I am doing `git checkout --ours .` each time, is there an automatic way to do that?. Also, I am not sure what is happening here, are older commits applied first?

Comment: My original would have tried to apply changes from newest to oldest, which would likely cause problems with conflicts. I've updated the answer to address that.

Comment: You should also remove merge commits.